# Como ocultar caracteres de um cpf usando substr_replace() em coluna de tabela?

Tags: php

Consegui ocultar os caracteres de um e-mail em uma tabela de listagem de funcionário usando `substr_replace()` deixando como exemplo `c*****s@personal.com`. Agora não sei como fazer isso no campo `cpf`.

Aqui está o exemplo no campo `email`:

```
echo '<td title="'.substr_replace($exibir_colunas['email'], '******', 1, strpos($exibir_colunas['email'], '@') - 2).'">'.substr_replace($exibir_colunas['email'], '*****', 1, strpos($exibir_colunas['email'], '@') - 2).'</td>';
```

Gostaria de fazer parecido no campo `cpf` deixando `012.***.***.90` utilizando `substr_replace()`.

```
echo '<td title="'.$exibir_colunas['cpf'].'">'.$exibir_colunas['cpf'].'</td>';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se tem certeza absoluta que haverá 14 caracteres (11 numeros mais 3 pontos), então basta aplicar no segundo parâmetro 4, que representa 3 digitos mais o ponto, e no terceiro parametro coloque o numero 3 negativo (1 ponto e 2 digitos )

```
<?php

$var = '100.222.333.44';

echo substr_replace($var, '***.***', 4, -3);
```

Se mesclar CPFs e CNPJs então você pode checar a quantidade de caracteres e ajustar, exemplo:

```
<?php

function mascara_doc($doc)
{
    if (strlen($doc) === 18) {
         return substr_replace($doc, '***.***/****', 3, -3);
    }

    return substr_replace($doc, '***.***', 4, -3);
}

var_dump(mascara_doc('100.222.333.44'));
var_dump(mascara_doc('12.345.678/1000-55'));
```

Exemplo online: https://ideone.com/OuyErt